# How to use rspec for sidekiq enterprise periodic jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, sidekiq

Ruby version: 2.6.3
Sidekiq Enterprise version: 2.0.1

I have integrated sidekiq periodic jobs using sidekiq-ent. However, when trying to run the test using RSpec I do not get to see any list of periodic jobs. Is there a way to test specifically with RSpec and view periodic jobs along with the scheduled time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the test", but mperham's wiki has instructions on testing ent periodic jobs: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Periodic-Jobs#testing

Comment: Yeah, could not verify the time the jobs were scheduled on. But with above suggested testing we could only test if the worker actually exits, which is fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to test the *schedule*, then you need to expand on the sample specs (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Periodic-Jobs#testing). You can do something like mock the Verifier object with an instance double and validate the arguments that it's being called with, or you create a `Sidekiq::Periodic::LoopSet` object, iterate over each loop in the LoopSet, and verify the contents of the `schedule` attribute.